# what does "wonder" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

He would remember his expression, remember the tears starting to well up in dark green eyes, and wonder.

Is the "wonder" here a noun or a verb?
What does it exactly mean?

Answer (score 3):

From the context, it's a verb. Though it *could* be a noun, particularly if that last comma wasn't there, it could mean "he would remember his expression, remember the tears, and [remember the] wonder".

But I'm pretty sure it's a verb.

In this case it means "and he would wonder", which means he would be deep in thought.

Comment: I agree that it's a verb.  It means he would wonder about something, but what exact thoughts would be going through his head is left to the reader's imagination to fill in.

Comment: The repetition of the verb *remember* in the second of the three members indicates that the zeugma branches between the auxiliary verb *would* and three main verbs in series, the first two being *remember* and the third *wonder.* In other words, read as "He would [*1*] remember his expression, [*2*] remember the tears starting to well up in dark green eyes, and [*3*] wonder," and not as "He would [*1*] remember his expression, [*2*] remember [*a*] the tears starting to well up in dark green eyes, and [*b*] wonder."